# MySQL key ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

Have the following problem

```
INSERT INTO statistics_new (SELECT * FROM statistics)
    -> 
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -> 
    -> end_date = IF(end_date < VALUES(end_date), VALUES(end_date), end_date);
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'end_date' in field list is ambiguous
```

When I tried to specify column and table aliases as it recommended in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html I had the same result.

Server version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

The following query runs without problem :

```
INSERT INTO statistics_new (SELECT * FROM statistics)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
end_date = VALUES(end_date)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e377)

Basically I think you want this:

```
INSERT INTO statistics_new (SELECT * FROM statistics)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
statistics_new.end_date = if(statistics_new.end_date < statistics.end_date, 
                             statistics.end_date, statistics_new.end_date);
```

Comment: And why we have so strnge behaviour without "statistics_new." prefix whn use IF in ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: Because the DB engine does not know which column to take since it has the same name in 2 tables. So you have to name the table.

Comment: This behaviour is not clear. Because 1) we can't add table alias to insertion table and neeed to prefix fieldswith full table name and 2) MySQL manual describes the only way to use insertion values through VALUES() statement, but we can use "selection_table.field" form and it isn't clear are this ways dothe same things. I.e. is "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE inserion.field = VALUES(selection.field)" the same as "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE insertion.field = selection.field"?

Comment: One more iteresting feature about this. Two queries:
1)
INSERT INTO statistics_new (SELECT * FROM statistics)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
statistics_new.end_date = statistics.end_date,
statistics_new.is_modified = if(statistics_new.end_date != statistics.end_date,1,0);
2)
INSERT INTO statistics_new (SELECT * FROM statistics)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
statistics_new.is_modified = if(statistics_new.end_date != statistics.end_date,1,0),
statistics_new.end_date = statistics.end_date;

UPDATE order changed.
First query set `is_modified` to 0 everytime,
Second will compare and set 0 or 1.

Comment: Thank you made my day, for some reason this was giving me Insufficient  index 64. It seems it was related to a the db sessions using the DB client (pycharm plugin). My bad luck.

Answer (score 0):

Both `statistics_new` and `statistics` have `end_date` column. Please differentiate between them in your SQL .

Answer (score 0):

if you try to set a variable in the last line it should be rather something like:

```
SET @end_date = IF(end_date < VALUES(end_date), VALUES(end_date), end_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to create a new table, you can use a subquery to rename the ambiguous fields. This requires listing all the fields though, so maybe not suitable to all use cases:

```sql
INSERT INTO statistics(end_date, field2) 
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT end_date as new_end_date, field2 
  FROM statistics
) q
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  end_date = IF(end_date < VALUES(end_date), VALUES(end_date), end_date);
```